# How can I display a Media picker image

Tags: umbraco7

Sorry this might be a newbie question but I am quite new to Umbraco.

I have a media picker set up on a document type, and it all works fine.
So I go to the template and enter

```
 @Umbraco.Field("bottomRightLarge")
```

this only gives me the ID of the image, how can I get this to show the actual image the user has selected?
 I am using UMBRACO 7 - and I have tried http://our.umbraco.org/projects/website-utilities/social-bookmarking-button/general-discussions/19360-Displaying-an-image-from-Media-Picker-in-a-web-page - but the XSLT ERRORS bug time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me

```
<umbraco:Macro runat="server" language="cshtml">
<img src="@Model.MediaById(Model.topleftsmall).umbracoFile" alt=""/>
</umbraco:Macro>
```

please note I was trying this on firefox 20.0.1, and the save just didnt work properly.

Answer (score 6):

Try using the umbraco image item if using webforms or umbraco media for mvc

```
<img src="@Umbraco.Media(model.articleImageOne).Url" alt="">
```

or

```
<umbraco:Image field="articleImageOne" runat="server" />
```